# Getting “Unspecified Error” while running Scripts from ALM 11.5

Tags: qtp, hp-quality-center, alm, hp-uft

I've made a connection to ALM with UFT 11.5 and when I run my scripts from UFT 11.5 its working perfectly fine, but I face issue when the same scripts are being run from ALM Test Lab. I am not sure whats happening.

I am getting Unspecified Error, I wonder why the same scripts which are running directly in UFT isn't getting ran from ALM.

**Scripts are running from ALM for QTP 11.0, it is only giving unspecified error for UFT 11.5 and I've also enabled the option "Allow other HP products to run tests and components"**

Please check the screenshots for error. I tried finding the answer for it but couldn't find anything :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Logs**

```
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:141 : 
FinalConstruct CAqtRemoteAgent has been created. CurrentRAObjectIndex = 3 File Line=43 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:183 : CAqtRemoteAgent::host_lock - m_CurrentRAObjectIndex - 3 File Line=206 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:183 : 
Construct CRemoteAgentThread has been created File Line=37 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:201 : SetMaxNoCommunicationDuration(120000) File Line=107 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:201 : host_lock Start File Line=907 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:226 : Lock Start File Line=34 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:228 : Refresh File Line=98 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:229 : Lock accept for '\\velomp2a\QCSHARE\repository\qc\CORPORATE_7\CORPORATE_SYSTEMS\tests\70845\67109-07-2014-11-46-46-830' File Line=47 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:229 : host_lock End (identifier = '\\velomp2a\QCSHARE\repository\qc\CORPORATE_7\CORPORATE_SYSTEMS\tests\70845\67109-07-2014-11-46-46-830', fRC = 1) File Line=920 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:229 : CAutoClose::Stop - Timer has stopped File Line=92 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:230 : CAqtRemoteAgent::get_value - m_CurrentRAObjectIndex - 3 File Line=181 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:235 : CRemoteAgentThread::get_value - external get_value 
name = SUPPORT_TEST_CONFIG,
value = YES
 File Line=561 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:297 : CAqtRemoteAgent::get_value - parameter = SUPPORT_TEST_CONFIG File Line=184 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:298 : CAqtRemoteAgent::is_host_ready, CurrentRAObjectIndex = 3 File Line=66 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:298 : CRemoteAgentThread::CreateRunningThread() init File Line=1167 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:46:47:298 : Start CreateQTAutomation File Line=51 ThreadId=1456 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:783 : Start InitTDPierInTulip File Line=1952 ThreadId=1456 
Error: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:811 : InitTDPierInTulip : pTDPier is null File Line=1967 ThreadId=1456 
Error: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:811 : failed to get pier in QTP File Line=68 ThreadId=1456 
Error: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:811 : Create Automation in QuickTest failed. return value = -2147467259 File Line=670 ThreadId=1456 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:812 : CRemoteAgentThread::TerminateRunningThread - Destroying running thread bTryToPostQuitMsg =1. File Line=1075 ThreadId=3232 
Error: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:812 : CRemoteAgentThread::is_host_ready - Failed to create running thread! ret = -2147467259 File Line=502 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:812 : CAqtRemoteAgent::is_host_ready,, value = 0 File Line=69 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:813 : CAqtRemoteAgent::get_value - m_CurrentRAObjectIndex - 3 File Line=181 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:814 : CAqtRemoteAgent::get_value - parameter = Test_set_end_supported File Line=184 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:814 : CAqtRemoteAgent::host_unlock - m_CurrentRAObjectIndex - 3 File Line=219 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:814 : host_unlock Start File Line=932 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:815 : Unlock Start File Line=73 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:815 : Unlock End for '\\velomp2a\QCSHARE\repository\qc\CORPORATE_7\CORPORATE_SYSTEMS\tests\70845\67109-07-2014-11-46-46-830' File Line=89 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:815 : host_unlock End (identifier = '\\velomp2a\QCSHARE\repository\qc\CORPORATE_7\CORPORATE_SYSTEMS\tests\70845\67109-07-2014-11-46-46-830', fRC = 1) File Line=943 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:815 : CAutoClose::Start - Started a new timer File Line=67 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:8:815 : CAutoClose::Start, AutoClose Timer Identifier is = 9722 File Line=70 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:10:815 : CAqtRemoteAgent::SetIsInUse - m_CurrentRAObjectIndex - 3 File Line=166 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:10:815 : FinalRelease CAqtRemoteAgent has been destroyed. CurrentRAObjectIndex = 3 File Line=60 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:10:816 : CRemoteAgentThread::TerminateRunningThread - Destroying running thread bTryToPostQuitMsg =1. File Line=1075 ThreadId=3232 
OK: 07/09/14 , 11:47:10:818 : CRemoteAgentThread has been destroyed. File Line=47 ThreadId=3232
```

Comment: I see you have enabled the log.  What does the log say?

Comment: I've added the logs as well in the question.. please take a look if you are getting it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow ALM to use your HP QTP/UFT remotely.
Set checkbox in 
Tools->options->Run->"Allow other HP products to run tests and components"
(In QTP 11 path looks like this).

Be sure also that you have got permissions to start automated tests on ALM.

And patches helped me as well
https://hpln.hp.com/page/unified-functional-testing-add

Comment: Hi Artur, I've already checked this option.. I've mentioned it in my question as well! :(

Comment: Sooo I remember, that I had got similar problem, and I installed some 2 patches as well, to integrate ALM and qtp.
Try this add-ins from link
https://hpln.hp.com/page/unified-functional-testing-add

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting the logs.  Unfortunately, I don't see any hints there.

Some suggestions I found by searching for "Quality Center Unspecified Error" on the web appear to indicate that re-installing QTP/UFT can help resolve the issue.  Have you tried to re-install?

If you select a test in Test Plan and then select the option to open it in UFT, does it open?  If not, do you get a more meaningful error message?

It's also worth noting that UFT 11.50 was very buggy on initial release and received A LOT of critical patches.  I would install all available patches, which I believe takes you up to UFT 11.53.  You can access the software patches from HP's support website.

If reinstalling and/or patching doesn't resolve the issue, this is probably best turned over to HP support for them to guide you through enabling different logs that will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it can be resolved by

1. disable UAC or bring it to low level
2. uninstall qtp, delete qc instalation folder
3. reinstall qtp with alm add in
4. install qc
5. in my computer properties, make sure all users have allow access for all the items
6. problem would be solved hopefully.

muthu
muthuramanc@ymail.com